# XAML DataBinding Clarity

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

Want to see if someone could help clear this up for me? Is there an advantage to DataBinding from the XAML Element to a value within the ViewModel(ex:1), or from the CodeBehind(ex:2) back to the Element like... HostName.Text?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding HostName}" /> --- (ex:1)
<TextBlock Name="HostName" /> --- (ex:2)
```

POGO

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Task;

namespace AppName.Models
{

public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Team { get; set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set;}
    public string Phone { get; set;}
    public string Email { get; set;}
    public string Role { get; set;}
    public string DisplayName => $"[LastName}, {FirstName}";
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand this question. Example1 is what people refer to as databinding - view model property is bound to control's Text property. When property changes on either end, the VM backing property is updated (if you use two-way binding and have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented). Example 2 is confusing. Setting HostName.Text property is usually in your code-behind file (but not a view model), but that's not databinding. Doing it from a ViewModel means your view model would need to be aware of your view and a particular textblock within it. That breaks the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I modified the 2nd statement to better reflect your correction... I guess what I'm trying to understand, is when you would choose one method over another? For instance, can ex:2 support Two-Way Binding.. or is example 2 not even considered binding? I thought it was because arent you binding to the Text property of the Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that it depends on your application and needs. When you're building a small application, using code behind or data binding to view models doesn't make much difference. It's easy to understand the flow and when to make updates. But as your app complexity goes up and your need to test your code, then you start to use patterns that makes your code more maintainable and testable. That's where the MVVM pattern came from.

Testing code in your code behind file is harder than just testing your business logic in your ViewModel class, and ensuring it works as expected.

Your example above is kind of simplistic because it's a TextBlock that only displays text and doesn't take input. A TextBox is a better example for binding since data can change in the view model or in the UI. Binding lets you back the displayed text with a property, so changes from any direction update the model property and UI automatically.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Entry" Text="{Binding SelectedValue , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CatalogViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string selectedValue;
    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get { return selectedValue; }
        set { SetProperty<string>(ref selectedValue, value); }
    }
...
}
```

The alternative to that is a lot of code in the code-behind file to keep things in sync between the TextBox and data elements.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Entry2" TextChanged="Entry2_TextChanged" />
```

Code behind:

```
private string entryText;
public string EntryText
{
    get { return entryText; }
    set
    {
        if (value != entryText)
        {
            entryText = value;
            Entry2.Text = entryText;
        }
    }
}
private void Entry2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    entryText = Entry2.Text;
}
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // initialize controls
    EntryText = "Default";
}
```

You've now coupled your business logic with the page layout and changes to either will cause a lot of changes. And testing the behavior of your code is harder to write and harder to mock.

And it just gets more complicated with multiple input controls and more complex controls, like ListViews and GridViews.

You should read up on MVVM if you're interested in the benefits of using view models and databinding to them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx.

Comment: Great description.. yea I am building something more complex and do want to follow MVVM logic. I have gone thru many tutorials online and read many articles, and I'm starting to more and more clarity as the days progress.  I still have not had an Aha moment. For instance, right now I have all of my Database Tables represented in POGO objects within the Model directory. But I don't always have a clear understanding of how to represent them in the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks. Are you using entity framework with your POCO classes? How the model and view model interact is a topic for debate in MVVM. If you're editing a list of Customers (for example), do you expose that model class in your UI binding or wrap each one in a view model class? I usually pass the mode class through the view model (but don't duplicate them). So my CustomerListViewModel has a property IList<Customer> Customers that is bound to a ListView in XAML. But that means you model classes need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to support databinding correctly.

Comment: I updated my original post to include a POCO class that corresponds to one of the database Tables. This is also duplicated within the WebService Project, which is using Entity Framework.  I tried to use it in my main Project but when I found out that it was currently impossible to sync with SQL Server via EF6 or Core, I had to go the WebService route.  I guess I can pull out the EF Core References from main Project since its not being used now.